# Promises and Deferred : .done() and .then() called though .resolve() is called on the Deferred object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, promise, jquery-deferred

I am new to Javascript and JQuery. As per my understanding,  .then() and .done() are fired as a result of resolve() on the deferred object. But in my code, though resolve() is not called, .then() and .done() are fired

```html
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Testing Promises</title>
</head>

<body>

<button type="button" onclick="test()"> Click Me</button>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

    function test() {
        var promise = $.when(another);
        promise.done(function () {
            console.log("another() done");
        });

        promise.done(function () {
            console.log("another() done 2");
        });

        promise.done(function () {
            console.log("another() done 3");
        });

        promise.fail(function (error) {
            console.log("Failed with error = ", error);
        });

        promise.then(function () {
            console.log("In then():");
        });

        console.log("test() done");
    }


    function another() {
        var def = $.Deferred();

        console.log("In another()");
        return def.promise();
    }
</script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$.when(another)` is an (immediately fulfilled) promise for the `another` function. You'll want to use

```
var promise = $.when(another());
```

or just

```
var promise = another();
```

to actually call the function and create the `def` that is never resolved.

Answer (score 1):

You're passing `$.when` a **function**, not a promise. It expects promises. If you pass it a promise (by actually calling `another`), you get the behavior you expect:

```js
function test() {
  var promise = $.when(another());
  //                          ^^-------------- change is here
  promise.done(function() {
    console.log("another() done");
  });

  promise.done(function() {
    console.log("another() done 2");
  });

  promise.done(function() {
    console.log("another() done 3");
  });

  promise.fail(function(error) {
    console.log("Failed with error = ", error);
  });

  promise.then(function() {
    console.log("In then():");
  });

  console.log("test() done");
}


function another() {
  var def = $.Deferred();
  // Added for testing - start
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log("waiting...");
  }, 400);
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log("waiting...");
  }, 800);
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log("resolving...");
    def.resolve();
  }, 1200);
  // Added for testing - end

  console.log("In another()");
  return def.promise();
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="test()">Click Me</button>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```